# mod_rewrite Probs

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am quite new to PHP and just getting started with mod_rewrite. I know the basic lingo but come stuck when I want to simply refer to the route directory

i.e. this is not probs

> RewriteRule ^settings/$ settings.php
>   [QSA,L]

But how to for example make:

> RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$
>   index.php?Page=$1 [QSA,L]

which generates /page/[page-name]

Just become

/[page-name]

?

Comment: Apache configuration issues should be on serverfault.

Comment: @hobodave: not necessarily. Jeff Attwood's opinion is "if your job title contains the word 'programmer', go with Stack Overflow," and I hope his opinion counts for something. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-modrewrite-so-or-sf

Comment: @outis: His opinion clearly didn't count. He had no upvotes, and the ones that said "belongs on SF" did. :P Regardless, that's why we vote. When I vote to close, I leave an explanation; it's not an invitation for debate.

Comment: @hobodave: considering he's a co-creator of SO (and hence definer of its purpose), it should count for something. As for voted answers, the number of votes indicates a very small sample size (at most three), which isn't enough to base conclusions on. I agree about the debate. The linked page is where debate should occur, which is the purpose of my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ index.php?Page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, you should place that rewrite rule after all the other specific rewrite rules you have, otherwise all requests will be redirected to `index.php?Page=...`.

Comment: hey thanks - yeah i tried that = i am using http://vanillaforums.org/addon/60/page-manager/50/50/ - but it seems when i do that none of my styles load ?

Comment: hmm thanks again but now that gives me "not found" i.e. for either /page/[page-name] or /[page-name] ?

Comment: "URLs need a ending dash though."

Comment: "URLs need a ending dash though." :) hey thanks again - not sure what you mean ? ^(.*/)$ index.php?Page=$1- [QSA,L] or ?

Comment: It means it'll only work if you access pages like this: `[page-name]/`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't understand you but it seems that you need such .htaccess file to solve your problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  # Ignore valid files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?Page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response - it seems when i add this none of my styles load ?

Comment: hey darren - thanks again. tried this but again didn't seem to work ? i.e. just redirects back to index.php ?

Comment: The `RewriteBase` is probably unnecessary.